# Image and Text aligning

Tags: html, css

I have a html page wherein Image and Text come adjacent to each other, as shown in the markup below:

```
<div><img src="image1.png"/><p>First Image</p></div>
<div><img src="image1.png"/><p>First Image</p></div>
```

I want the Image and text align side by side under every DIV and all divs to be listed in the page.

Please help me how to achieve this with CSS, without using tables.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "under every div" and "all divs to be listed in the page".

Comment: Yes sure.. I post a link in a mintue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `display: inline-block`

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/vhTL4/)

Comment: Thanks.. I am too close.. But please check the jsFiddle link again for my update. When the para is long, it descends to the next line... Pls help me on how to bring this entire paragraph adjacent to the image.

Comment: The link is [link]:(http://jsfiddle.net/vhTL4/1/)

Comment: Set a defined width http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/vhTL4/2/

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you right, you wan't your text to be inline with your image. well if that's the case then the reason this doesn't happen already is becuase a paragraph `<p>` element is a block element so it would be the whole width of its containing parent. If you wan't to display it inline use display inline on your `<p>` tag like this

```
div p{ /* Change this according to your selectors. */
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline;
 }
 div img{
   display:inline-block;
 }
 div p{
   display:inline-block;
 }
```